# QDockWidget::background-color not applied when docked

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QDockWidget`:

[image]

I would like to alert the user to certain events by setting the **background color** of the title bar.

I have achieved this by setting the style sheet for my `DockWidget`:

```
void DockWidget::setCriticalAlert()
{
    setStyleSheet("QDockWidget { background-color:red; }");
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

The problem is that the `background-color` doesn't get applied when the `QDockWidget` is docked:

[image]

How can I get the background color to be applied when the `QDockWidget` is docked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Qt.

[Issue 10537](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-10537)

Quoting from the linked issue:

> The problem is that in QDockWidget::paintEvent, there is a
>   isFloating() condition before drawing PE_FrameDockWidget. We cannot
>   jsut remove this condition as it would break the other style (that
>   does not whish to draw frame when the dockwidget is docked) We cannot
>   either use PE_Widget to draw the frame as then it goes over the
>   dockwidget's title The solution is maybe to introduce a new
>   PE_FrameDockWidgetDocked primitive element. Or some
>   SH_DockWidget_DrawDockedFrame stylehint to draw the frame in every
>   cases.

Answer (score 1):

a valid workaround seems to be to set the stylesheet of the parent, and use the class-and-id selector.  Forgive the python formatted code but the concept is the same - in this case, 'dock' is a QDockWidget which has been given an object name using setObjectName(), and its parent, the QMainWindow, is 'self':

```
self.setStyleSheet("QDockWidget#"+str(dock.objectName())+"::title {background-color:red}")
```

In PyQt5.5, this works at runtime, i.e., can be changed on the fly.

Comment: Note this works for the title bar, but not for the dockwidget itself (tried with Qt 5.15.2)!

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution like this:
Firstly put a frame behind all the widgets of dockwidget's center widget, as the background.
Then set stylesheet for the frame.

By this way, we could change the background color of dockwidget.

Or you can extend the dockwidget and overwrite the function

```
 void QDockWidget::setWidget(QWidget *widget)
```

using private/qdockwidget_h. and add a frame as this widget's father.